# Who is allowed to remove his/her own posts?

Tags: support

The unregistered user [petra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2611/petra) tried to remove [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line/7451#7451) as it really isn't an answer. However, it seems that unregistered users don't get to see a "delete" link below the post. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Feature: The Stack Exchange software doesn't trust you very much if you aren't logged in.

Comment: For the record, I've now deleted the answer that sparked this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Shog's accepted answer to [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222):

> ### When can't I delete my own post?
>
> You can't delete your answer if it has been accepted.
>
> You can't delete your question if it has more than two answers, if an answer has a score >= 2, or it has been closed less than 48 hours ago.
>
> You can't delete any of your questions or answers if you haven't registered your account (associated an OpenID with it).

Comment: Thanks. So I guess that in such a case, flagging for moderator attention is the correct approach.

Comment: Is it good to delete your own (correct) answers if others have given more complete ones?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to the actual question, but moderators can delete posts.  So if this arises again, flag the post for moderator attention.

(I just left a note on that answer saying that I'd delete it once you and Petra had seen my note saying that I'd delete it...)